# C++ : Optimal Complexity function

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

I have been asked a question in an interview :

We have packages as below (packages as in components of a software system) -

pkg1 -> pkg2, pkg3, pkg4

pkg2 -> pkg5, pkg6

pkg7 -> pkg8, pkg9

pkg9 -> pkg10, pkg11

Where, Pkg1 has dependency on pkg2, 3, 4.

pkg2 has dependency on pkg5, 6 and so on.

These packages are to be built (compiled). Independent packages can be built parallely for fastest compilation.

Write a C++ function to list independent packages and dependent packages, with time complexity as better as possible. Its upto you to design the function signature, so you can chose what container will your input package data be.

Output (on the stdout) - 
Independent Packages - pkg3, pkg4, pkg5, pkg6, pkg8, pkg10, pkg11
Dependent Packages - pkg1, pkg2, pkg7, pkg9

---

In my solution, I used a std::map for input packages, and used std::set and std::vector for the Dependent and Independent Packages respectively.

The time complexity I could achieve was O(mn) where m is number of dependent packages and n is number of independent packages.
Can we achieve more than that? How? Any help/guidance appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
Thought, I will give my implementation here -

```
#include <iostream>
void filterPackages(const std::map<int, std::vector<int> > &packages)
{
    std::vector<int> potential_independent_packages;
    std::set<int> dependent_packages;

    for(auto iter : packages)
    {
        dependent_packages.insert(iter.first);
        for(auto iter1 : iter.second)
        {
            potential_independent_packages.push_back(iter1);
        }
    }

    std::cout<<"Independent package - ";
    for( auto iter2 : potential_independent_packages)
    {
        if(dependent_packages.found(iter2) == std::set::end)
        {
            std::cout<<iter2;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Dependent packages - ";
    for( auto iter3 : dependent_packages)
    {
        std::cout<<iter3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Time complexity of operations on the various c++ standard container implementations is well [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) already, and you rather should refer  there first, befor asking here.

Comment: The problem statement is very vague. What is the limiting variable to optimize for? The total number of packages? Only packages without any dependencies at all shall be counted as `independent`? Do packages without dependencies appear in the input map's keys or must their names/numbers be collected from the dependencies of other packages? Do outputs need to be sorted by package name/number? Can I really choose any input structure at all? I could just demand the input to be a `map`-like container that can list all values in `O(n)` time together with whether they appear as key or not.

Comment: To answer user10605163's valid questions -
The total number of packages? - assume to be in 100s
Only packages without any dependencies at all shall be counted as independent? - Yes
Do packages without dependencies appear in the input map's keys or must their names/numbers be collected from the dependencies of other packages? Yes, packages without dependencies must be collected from the dependencies. The essence is to select an optimal input data structure as well.

Comment: Do outputs need to be sorted by package name/number? No
Can I really choose any input structure at all? I could just demand the input to be a map-like container that can list all values in O(n) time together with whether they appear as key or not. -Yes, its your function, so you can chose and publish the signature. I chose std::map as well.

Comment: Your code is actually `O(n*m*ln m)` worst-case where n is the number of _total_ packages and m the number of dependent packages if all dependent packages depend on all other packages. Then `potential_independent_packages` will be of size `n*m` and you are going to check `dependent_packages` for each of them for a factor of `ln(m)`. You are also potentially printing packages multiple times.

Comment: Still questions: Are you going for average- or worst-case time complexity? Are package numbers guaranteed to be consecutive (i.e. the highest package number is the total package count minus one)? Did I understand you correctly that all input containers from the standard library are fine? Because again I could just use an input container that has a `O(r)` function returning a list of independent packages where `r` is the number of such and that would obviously be optimal.

Comment: [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) might help.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clearly stated in the description but I presume you meant that package cannot be compiled if some of the packages it is dependent upon haven't been compiled yet.

With this assumption, there is a fairly simple code that optimizes the compilation order. Compute depth of dependency for each package and then compile in parallel packages
of the same depth starting with packages of lowest depth.

(What is "depth of dependency"? Think of the dependency as a directed tree,
then the depth of the element is the longest path from the element to the leaves it depends upon. Formally, if package has no dependencies then its depth is zero and for others Depth[package] = max(Depth[depends_of_the_package])+1. Note that packages of the same depth are necessarily independent of each other)

I would use following code

```
class PackageOptimizer
{
    public:
    struct PackageDependency
    {  
        size_t Count() const
        {
            return m_end - m_begin;
        }
        size_t m_begin;
        size_t m_end;
    };

    vector<size_t> FindLeaves()
    {
        vector<size_t> leaves;
        for(size_t i = 0; i<m_deps.size(); i++)
        {
            if(m_deps[i].m_begin == m_deps[i].m_end)
                leaves.push_back(i);
        }

        return leaves;
    }

    vector<int> ComputeDepthMap()
    {
        vector<int> Depth(m_deps.size());
        vector<int> Count(m_deps.size(),0);
        vector<size_t> currSet = FindLeaves();
        vector<size_t> nextSet;

        int currDepth = 0;
        while(!currSet.empty())
        {
           for(size_t elem : currSet)
           {
               Depth[elem] = currDepth;

               for( size_t  upPackage = m_depsInv[elem].m_begin;
                            upPackage < m_depsInv[elem].m_end; 
                            upPackage++)
                {
                    Count[upPackage]++;

                    if(Count[upPackage] == m_deps[upPackage].Count())
                    {
                        nextSet.push_back(upPackage);
                    }
                }
           } 
           swap(nextSet, currSet);
           currDepth++;
           nextSet.clear();
        }

        return Depth;
    }

    private:
    // package i is dependent on
    // m_indices[m_deps[i].m_begin], m_indices[m_deps[i].m_begin+1], ... m_indices[m_deps[i].m_end-1]
    vector<PackageDependency>   m_deps; 
    vector<size_t>              m_indices;

    // following packages are dependant on package i
    // m_indicesInv[m_depsInv[i].m_begin], m_indicesInv[m_depsInv[i].m_begin+1], ... m_indicesInv[m_deps[i].m_end-1]
    vector<PackageDependency>   m_depsInv; 
    vector<size_t>              m_indicesInv;
};
```

It just lacks methods to initiate `m_deps, m_indices, m_depsInv, m_indicesInv`,
but those aren't hard. With `Depth` computed you can easily organize packages appropriate to the order of execution. Also, you do need to ensure that there are no loops of dependency in the packages else this code will never finish.

In terms of performance this algorithm takes around `O(n + m)`,
where is `n` is the number of packages and `m` is the total number of dependencies. Creation of `m_deps, m_indices, m_depsInv, m_indicesInv` should take around the same amount of time.

Although, in real life, different packages require different amount of time to compile
and you always have a limit to the number of packages you can compile at the same time efficiently.